# Suppose that $A$ is a real symmetric singular matrix with entries only $0$ or $1$ with all diagonal entries of $A$ being zero.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A$ is a real symmetric *singular matrix* with entries only $0$ or $1$ with all diagonal entries of $A$ being zero. Also assume that all the rows of $A$ are nonzero. Let $P(x)$ be the characteristic polynomial of $A$. Is it true that the coefficient of smallest power of $x$ in $P(x)$ can not be $\pm 1$?

I made this observation and now I am trying to find a counterexample. but I have not got any one. please give some idea/hint.

Comment: By 'the smallest power of $x$ in $P(x)$', do you mean the smallest power of $x$ for which the coefficient is non-zero? Also, what observation have you made? You are asking us whether or not the statement is true

Comment: yes, you are correct. yes, i am asking about the true/false behaviour. I have calculate the characteristic polynomial of many matrices and I found that the coefficient is not 1 or -1. So is it true or we can have a counterexample.

Comment: So you are trying to determine whether or not there is an example of such a matrix $A$ whose characteristic polynomial has coefficient $1$ or $-1$ for the smallest power of $x$ with non-zero coefficient?

Comment: @Oliver House, yes you are correct

Comment: Can any body give some hints/ideas for the problem.